Flutter Intl.message method: How the order of args are determined?
I'm trying to use Intl.message method directly
so I can do kind of similar thing which is done in auto-generated L10n code by Intl package,
but slightly customized.
I have these .arb files. Note that the order of appearance of person and food is reversed in each other languages.
// Japanese
{
  "@@locale": "ja",
  "text1": "{food}を食べるのは{person}",
  "@text1": {
    "placeholder": {
      "food": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "person": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}

// English
{
  "@@locale": "en",
  "text1": "{person} eats {food}",
  "@text1": {
    "placeholder": {
      "food": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "person": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}

Having this .arb files, I tried getting localized string with this code.
final translated = Intl.message('', name: 'text1', desc: '', args: ['banana', 'gorilla'])

The result was banana eats gorilla in English, 'gorillaを食べるのはbanana' in Japanese. This is not what I expected of course, and I don't know why I'm getting this result.
What defines the order of args?
If it happens to be based on the order of appearance in .arb file, then why it takes the English order?
I don't see any priority setting nor a base-localized relationship like iOS localization.
Update1
Here's my l10n.yaml file. I specify Japanese file here.
arb-dir: lib/l10n
template-arb-file: intl_ja.arb
output-localization-file: l10n.dart
output-class: L10n


If you followed a official guide in step #3 you set template-arb-file: app_en.arb which is your default template file. Based on that file the generated class is created.
For example, if your default language is English, you could remove @text from the Japanese and it would still work, as Japanese is not the default language. If you would require 3 placeholders for Japanese, but only 2 for English, you need to define them in the English placeholder section, not in the translation itself.

I've added an update with my l10n.yaml contents. Maybe Intl.message doesn't look up l10n.yaml???

Based on your .arb files and l10n.yaml a L10n class should be generated. Your usage in code should be something like L10n.of(context).text1(food, person). Don't forget about step7 from the guide

As I wrote above I don't want to use the generated code as it is. So the title of my question starts with "Intl.message method:".

I haven't used Intl directly, but I think you are using it wrong. Check out this article https://medium.com/i18n-and-l10n-resources-for-developers/how-to-internationalize-a-flutter-app-using-intl-and-intl-translation-d5bf95f951fb Using the generated files will make your life easier, and the args should be placed correctly
